# how to write array object content in excel through selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
    int col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id=\"transactionListData\"]/thead/tr/th")).size();
    int row =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id=\"transactionListData\"]/tbody/tr")).size();
    //ArrayList<Object[]> mydata = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object [][] ob = new Object[row][col];
    for( int i=1; i<=row; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=col; j++)
        {
            String text =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='transactionListData']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText();
            //System.out.println("text " +text);
            ob[i][j] = text;

        }
    }
    try {
        String s = util.writeIntoExcel(ob, row, col);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return flag;
}
```

---

I have passed ob in below function to write its content in to excel file. but unable to print where ob is a object array Object [][] ob = new Object[row][col];. I am getting an error where i am trying  to write data in to excel regarding Object in to string conversion.

---

```
public static String writeIntoExcel(Object ob, int rowi,int colj ) throws IOException
{
    int rowcount =  rowi;
    int colcount = colj;
    Object oa[][]  = new Object[rowcount][colcount];
    oa =  (Object[][]) ob;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Transacton History");

    for (int i=1; i<=rowcount ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=colcount ; j++)
        {
            String val = (String) oa[i][j];
            Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
            row.createCell(colj).setCellValue(val);
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("\"\\\\btfin.com\\filesrv\\User\\Offshore\\SG1\\L097117\\user\\My Documents\\workbook.xlsx");
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

    return "Data is written";
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting? Add that info and any other relevant info to your question.

Comment: You should spend some time reading some tutorials on this. The way you are doing this is not very efficient and is confusing. Why are you passing around an `Object` instead of a specific data type like a string array? If you pass in an array, you don't need to pass in row and col because you can get that from the array dimensions itself. Don't return things like "Data is written", instead return a boolean... `true` if it succeeded or `false` if it didn't... or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question above is :

```
    Object [][] ob = new Object[row][col];
    for( int i=1; i<=row; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=col; j++)
        {
            String text =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='transactionListData']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText();
            //System.out.println("text " +text);
            ob[i-1][j-1] = text;                
        }
    }
```

// rest everything is fine..

```
public static String writeIntoExcel(Object[][] sob ) throws IOException
{

    //String oa[][]  = sob;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Transacton History");
    Object cellvalue = null;                         
    for (int i=0; i<=sob.length ; i++)
    {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
        for (int j=0; j<=sob[i].length ; j++)
        {
            Cell cell=row.createCell(j+1);
            cellvalue = sob[i][j];
            if (cellvalue instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String)(cellvalue));
            else if (cellvalue instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer)cellvalue);

            cell.setCellValue((String)cellvalue);
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("");
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    workbook.close();

    return "Data is written";
```